# Does a word in German exist that describes someone who works on something with passion?

Tags: translation, english-to-german, word-choice, single-word-request

Currently I am writing a CV for myself in German for an IT job.

Because I am very passionate and love working in IT and informatics field, I would like to describe that as clearly as possible.

I tried using a dictionary to get the right word, and I got expressions like:

> leidenschaftlich
>   feurig
>   heißblütig
>   stürmisch
>   glutvoll

For me those words sound a little bit strange. *Leidenschaftlich* is a general term, and the other terms are more for love and passion in a physical sense, but not in IT CV sense.

Can you give me any suggestion?

Comment: I would say passionate about IT in english. I tried to use dictionary, but the translation sounds strange.

Comment: Why strange? You have to put that in the question, you can [edit] it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I consider *leidenschaftlich* as appropriate. There is a famous quote from the philosopher *Hegel*:

> Nichts wirklich Wichtiges ist ohne Leidenschaft erreicht worden.

A possible and more professionally sounding alternative is

> engagiert.

Answer (score 2):

*passionate* translates to the German *leidenschaftlich*.

There is also an idiom that fits perfectly what you intend to say:

> Ich bin mit Leib und Seele Programmierer.

Both would fit your description, but both I would consider a bit thick in a job application.

Answer (score 2):

> Ich bin mit Leib und Seele Programmierer.

geht, aber ist nicht ganz auf der Höhe der Zeit. In den 50ern-70ern wäre das vollkommen in Ordnung gewesen. Da der Leib beim Programmieren etwas kurz kommt, passt es auch auf der wörtlichen Ebene nicht so gut, wie es etwa für einen Profifussballer passen würde.

> leidenschaftlich

ist da schon besser, auch wenn es ein wenig stark ist, und daher eher von relativierenden Floskeln begleitet werden müsste, nicht verstärkenden. In erster Linie passt die Leidenschaft zum leidenschaftlichen Liebhaber und könnte, sollte sie weiter betont werden, bedeuten, dass beim Programmieren Deine Vernunft zu kurz zu kommen droht.

Als Fremdwort gleichen Wortstamms bietet sich außerdem ***passioniert*** an. Es wird selten in Fragen der romantischen Liebe und des Unterleibs verwendet, so dass es mir in einem nüchternen Lebenslauf besser geeignet scheint, als das ansonsten gleichbedeutende *leidenschhaftlich*, welches aber insbesondere in informellen Gesprächen zu bevorzugen wäre - *passioniert* wäre da oft zu distanziert.